# Is my server being used as a proxy or being attacked?

Tags: web-application, network, attacks, apache, ubuntu

I have an Ubuntu, Apache, Passenger, and Rails 4 project on AWS EC2.

I am unfamiliar with the security and server side of my project. Recently, my site was down because of "too many users" so when I checked my

```
tail -f log/production.log
```

I saw that I was getting non-stop GET requests from random IPs to my home page.  The requests have not stopped and continue to flood my server.

**Is my server being used as a proxy or is it being attacked?  How can I prevent this from continuing to happen?**

I attempted to use this guide but as you will see from my other SO post, I was unsuccessful and was only able to stop ALL requests including valid ones.
https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/ProxyAbuse
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29401312/log-shows-constant-get-requests-from-unknown-ips

Log - this grouping repeats with a new IP nonstop

```
I, [2015-04-02T16:38:47.692152 #11851]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/_google_analytics.html.erb (0.1ms)
I, [2015-04-02T16:38:47.692709 #11851]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 9ms (Views: 8.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
I, [2015-04-02T16:38:49.073504 #11851]  INFO -- : Started GET "/" for 54.252.254.204 at 2015-04-02 16:38:49 +0000
I, [2015-04-02T16:38:49.077260 #11851]  INFO -- : Processing by HomeController#home_page as */*
I, [2015-04-02T16:38:49.084489 #11851]  INFO -- :   Rendered home/_sign_up_modal.html.erb (1.6ms)
I, [2015-04-02T16:38:49.084799 #11851]  INFO -- :   Rendered home/home_page.html.erb within layouts/application (6.2ms)
I, [2015-04-02T16:38:49.085349 #11851]  INFO -- :   Rendered /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/stripe-rails-0.3.1/app/views/stripe/_js.html.erb (0.1ms)
I, [2015-04-02T16:38:49.086550 #11851]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/_google_analytics.html.erb (0.0ms)
I, [2015-04-02T16:38:49.087121 #11851]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 10ms (Views: 8.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
I, [2015-04-02T16:38:50.166665 #11851]  INFO -- : Started GET "/" for 107.23.255.12 at 2015-04-02 16:38:50 +0000
I, [2015-04-02T16:38:50.169943 #11851]  INFO -- : Processing by HomeController#home_page as */*
I, [2015-04-02T16:38:50.176601 #11851]  INFO -- :   Rendered home/_sign_up_modal.html.erb (1.4ms)
I, [2015-04-02T16:38:50.176924 #11851]  INFO -- :   Rendered home/home_page.html.erb within layouts/application (5.5ms)
I, [2015-04-02T16:38:50.177425 #11851]  INFO -- :   Rendered /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/stripe-rails-0.3.1/app/views/stripe/_js.html.erb (0.1ms)
```

And another set from a different time period:

```
I, [2015-04-03T19:37:02.737535 #8097]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/_google_analytics.html.erb (0.1ms)
I, [2015-04-03T19:37:02.738015 #8097]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 8ms (Views: 7.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
I, [2015-04-03T19:37:06.459500 #8097]  INFO -- : Started GET "/" for 54.255.254.236 at 2015-04-03 19:37:06 +0000
I, [2015-04-03T19:37:06.462434 #8097]  INFO -- : Processing by HomeController#home_page as */*
I, [2015-04-03T19:37:06.468158 #8097]  INFO -- :   Rendered home/_sign_up_modal.html.erb (1.2ms)
I, [2015-04-03T19:37:06.468466 #8097]  INFO -- :   Rendered home/home_page.html.erb within layouts/application (4.8ms)
I, [2015-04-03T19:37:06.469006 #8097]  INFO -- :   Rendered /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/stripe-rails-0.3.1/app/views/stripe/_js.html.erb (0.1ms)
I, [2015-04-03T19:37:06.470022 #8097]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/_google_analytics.html.erb (0.1ms)
I, [2015-04-03T19:37:06.470502 #8097]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 8ms (Views: 7.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
I, [2015-04-03T19:37:07.079266 #8097]  INFO -- : Started GET "/" for 54.183.255.140 at 2015-04-03 19:37:07 +0000
I, [2015-04-03T19:37:07.081831 #8097]  INFO -- : Processing by HomeController#home_page as */*
I, [2015-04-03T19:37:07.087211 #8097]  INFO -- :   Rendered home/_sign_up_modal.html.erb (1.2ms)
I, [2015-04-03T19:37:07.087518 #8097]  INFO -- :   Rendered home/home_page.html.erb within layouts/application (4.6ms)
I, [2015-04-03T19:37:07.088029 #8097]  INFO -- :   Rendered /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/stripe-rails-0.3.1/app/views/stripe/_js.html.erb (0.1ms)
I, [2015-04-03T19:37:07.089000 #8097]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/_google_analytics.html.erb (0.1ms)
I, [2015-04-03T19:37:07.089471 #8097]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 7ms (Views: 6.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
I, [2015-04-03T19:37:09.102373 #8097]  INFO -- : Started GET "/" for 107.23.255.12 at 2015-04-03 19:37:09 +0000
I, [2015-04-03T19:37:09.105359 #8097]  INFO -- : Processing by HomeController#home_page as */*
I, [2015-04-03T19:37:09.111001 #8097]  INFO -- :   Rendered home/_sign_up_modal.html.erb (1.2ms)
I, [2015-04-03T19:37:09.111348 #8097]  INFO -- :   Rendered home/home_page.html.erb within layouts/application (4.8ms)
I, [2015-04-03T19:37:09.111855 #8097]  INFO -- :   Rendered /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/stripe-rails-0.3.1/app/views/stripe/_js.html.erb (0.1ms)
```

The only difference with each request is that the GET is from a different 54.###.##.### IP that changes each time. **None of them are users, I am sure of that.**

```
Started GET "/" for 54.###.##.### at 2015-04-01 21:37:44 +0000
```

And my .conf

/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName ec2-54-###-###-##.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
  # !!! Be sure to point DocumentRoot to 'public'!
  DocumentRoot /etc/projects/myapp/public

    <Directory /etc/projects/myapp/public>
            #Options FollowSymLinks
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
            AllowOverride All
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

I can provide more information if needed.

What can I do to solve this issue?

Comment: An excerpt of the logs might be helpful

Comment: @wireghoul thank you for your guidance.  I have added the logs and my .conf file

Comment: Based on the log excerpt you're not being used as a proxy, it is likely something else causing it. The requests are about 3 per second peak, which should not be the cause. Assuming your too many users errors were from the web server you could check the error log for more information

Comment: Can you provide the first three octets of several of the source IP addresses?

Comment: Likely you are suffering from a Distributed Denial of Service (DDOS) attack.  All the IP addresses are likely spoofed.  You should contact the security department of your Internet Service Provider (ISP).  If they are a decent ISP, they will be able to confirm at least whether this seems to be a DDOS attack.  Whether or not they'll help you out blocking the traffic I cannot say (some will do it for free, others only if you have an extended protection service contract with them).

Comment: @cybermike IP spoofing only works when you don't need a reply (common with UDP-based attacks). For an HTTP request to succeed you do need a reply (to establish the connection), so IP spoofing is impossible (other than in extreme cases where the attacker controls a router between your server and the internet, but even if that's the case I doubt they'd use it for DoS).

Comment: DDOS not DOS ... multiple computers ... the IP addresses are likely not the attacker's IP addresses, even if they are all from the 54.x.x.x range. The real point is that tracing IP address from his point-of-scope is not likely to be effective. An ISP has wider perspective ... are all the GETS coming from one particular border gateway router? Or just two?  Blocks can be put into place.  But I missed the top where the OP mentions his server is part of Amazon Cloud ... he should contact AWS' security team.

Comment: @BobBrown I added more logs with the IPs

Comment: @cybermike how would you suggest stopping this?

Comment: You can easily deny all requests from that subnet with a open source firewall. Can't say it's a DDoS or just a error. I would start by trying to find out where that IP is, who it is, and how it's getting to my server using what ports.

Answer (score 2):

This could either be a DDOS, albeit a low scale one, or Cash-overflow attack (given that you're on AWS)
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cash_Overflow

Edit: Also worth noting, that if someone is attempting to use your server as a proxy, you would see something like this in your Apache logs:

```
X.X.X.X - [20/Apr/2015:12:39:11 +0100] "GET http://somewherethatisnotyou.com HTTP/1.1" 404 395 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0"
```

Where X.X.X.X is attempting to GET another site through yours.

Further reading, and how to disable accessing any host not configured: https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/ProxyAbuse