# Spam GET And POST Requests - Are They Dangerous?

Tags: http, vulnerability, server, logging, nginx

I am getting a lot of spam GET and POST requests lately which some of them look like this:

```
"GET /config/getuser?index=0 HTTP/1.1" 404 143 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0"
```

and:

```
"\x03\x00\x00/*\xE0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00Cookie: mstshash=Administr" 400 173 "-" "-"
```

As far as I know these are trying known vulnerabilities in bulk but I am unsure.

So in my case where I only  have a single html file with nothing but text and a link in an up-to-date Debian server with NGINX, are they still pose a security threat? if yes how?

Thanks!

Comment: *"So in my case where I only have a single html file with nothing but text and a link in an up-to-date Debian server with NGINX, are they still pose a security threat? if yes how?"* - probably it is not a problem for you. But, it is not so much about what you __intend__ to do (serve a static html file) but what your server is __able__ to do based on your setup. Even if your goal is only to serve static html files you might have enabled features which can be used to attack your server, even though you don't need these features for static html files.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich *"based on your setup"* Is the default NGINX config vulnerable? What are the ways to defend against these attacks/exploits?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is my server being used as a proxy or being attacked?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/85105/is-my-server-being-used-as-a-proxy-or-being-attacked)

Comment: @fedqx: *"Is the default NGINX config vulnerable?"* - which _default config_ you are talking about? I don't think that there is such a thing. There might be default configurations with various packaging of nginx (i.e. different Linux distributions etc) but there is no overall default.  *"What are the ways to defend against these attacks/exploits?"* - in general: keep your configuration as minimal as needed. If you want to serve only static files make sure that's all what can be done with the config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No vulnerabilities are typically not shared across different software or hardware platforms or even different versions of the affected software. What you posted appears to be a precursor or exploitation attempt for [CVE-202-25078](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2020-25078), a D-LINK router vulnerability. Typically any IP address on the internet receives a lot of nuisance traffic trying to collect information that once lived on that IP address, looking for proxy servers, guessing passwords or various exploits. Many of which come from botnets that take no care to determine if what they are targeting may in fact be something suitable to send the traffic to. This is normal internet background traffic and not a threat to your server.

Comment: Thanks! It was really bothering me, now I can just ignore them.







Edit: BTW sorry for late response.